# How to create a scrum board that contains only EPIC?

Tags: jira

I have a usecase in which I want to track only EPICs in JIRA.
I created a dashboard and used a filter but the EPIC are not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Boards and dashboards are different in Jira.

What i understand that you want to show only "Epics" on a scrum board. This is possible. You need only to add the active sprint to each Epic.

This is not possible from he backlog. You need to edit each Epic then add active sprint on the sprint field.

Regards,
Seif,